# How composite sprites scale together with libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I have composited my sprites to build a monster truck with customizable bumpers, cabs, spoilers wheels etc. The class that holds these `Sprite`s is `MTruck` and I can draw it perfectly provided I stay with scale 1.0.

```
    mWheels.setPosition(posX + 17 * scale, posY);
    mCab.setPosition(posX + 22 * scale, posY + 7 * scale);
    mFender.setPosition(posX, posY + 75 * scale);
```

`mWheels` is positioned at the y origin of the Truck and `mFender` at the x origin.

I've tried all sorts of values for scale and extracting it separate from the scale I apply to `mWheels`, `mCab` etc but all that happens is the sprites scale but their positions become misaligned.

I'm going to have to render to a texture and scale that as I whole if I can't crack this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps, Set origin could help you:

```
void    setOrigin(float originX, float originY)
```

> Sets the origin in relation to the sprite's position for scaling and
>   rotation.

```
float   getOriginX()

The origin influences setPosition(float, float), 
                      setRotation(float) and the expansion direction 
                      of scaling setScale(float, float)

float   getOriginY()

The origin influences setPosition(float, float), 
                      setRotation(float) and the expansion direction of
                      scaling setScale(float, float)
```

1. http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html

**NEW EDIT:** maybe if you are customizing the vehicle on a menu for example, as is practicable after this the customized vehicle and create an image at runtime, and scale, an use this image in Sprite, for  maybe it's easier, but it's just an idea

Comment: Thanks, as simple as that. Once I realised `Sprite.scale` adds its parameter to instead of overwriting existing scale.